# How would I optimize this? I need to pull data from different tables and use results of queries in queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Please propose an approach I should follow since I am obviously missing the point.  I am new to SQL and still think in terms of MS Access.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:  Like I said, don't worry about the detail, I just want to know how I would do this in SQL.

I have the following tables:

Hrs_Worked (staff, date, hrs)  (200 000+ records)
Units_Done (team, date, type) (few thousand records)
Rate_Per_Unit (date, team, RatePerUnit) (few thousand records)
Staff_Effort (staff, team, timestamp)  (eventually 3 - 4 million records)

SO I need to do the following:

1)  Calculate what each team earned by multiplying their units with RatePerUnit and Grouping on Team and Date.  I create a view TeamEarnPerDay:

```
Create View teamEarnPerDay AS
        SELECT  
               ,Units_Done.Date, 
               ,Units_Done.TeamID, 
               ,Sum([Units_Done]*[Rate_Per_Unit.Rate]) AS Earn
        FROM Units_Done INNER JOIN Rate_Per_Unit 
        ON (Units_Done.quality = Rate_Per_Unit.quality) 
        AND (Units_Done.type = Rate_Per_Unit.type) 
        AND (Units_Done.TeamID = Rate_Per_Unit.TeamID) 
        AND (Units_Done.Date = Rate_Per_Unit.Date)
        GROUP BY 
                 Units_Done.Date, 
                 Units_Done.TeamID;
```

2)  Count the TEAM's effort by Grouping Staff_Effort on Team and Date and counting records.  This table has a few million records.
I have to cast the timestamp as a date....

```
CREATE View team_effort AS
SELECT 
       TeamID 
      ,CAST([Timestamp] AS Date) as TeamDate, 
      ,Count(Staff_EffortID) AS TeamEffort
FROM Staff_Effort
GROUP BY
        TeamID
        ,CAST([Timestamp] AS Date);
```

3)  Calculate the Team's Rate_of_pay:  (1) Team_earnings / (2) Team_effort 
    I use the 2 views I created above.  This view's performance drops but is still acceptable to me.

```
Create View team_rate_of_pay AS
  SELECT 
        tepd.Date 
       ,tepd.TeamID 
       ,tepd.Earn 
       ,tepd.TeamBags 
       ,[Earn]/[TeamEffort] AS teamRate
FROM teamEarnPerDay 
INNER JOIN team_effort 
ON (teamEarnPerDay.Date = team_effort.TeamDate) 
AND (teamEarnPerDay.TeamID = team_effort.TeamID);
```

4)  Group Staff_Effort on Date and Staff and count records to get each individuals's effort. (share of the team effort)
I have to cast the Timestamp as a date....

```
Create View staff_effort AS
SELECT 
   TeamID
  ,StaffID
  ,CAST([Timestamp] AS Date) as StaffDate
  ,Count(Staff_EffortID) AS StaffEffort
FROM Staff_Effort
GROUP BY 
  ,TeamID
  ,StaffID
  ,CAST([Timestamp] AS Date);
```

5)  Calculate Staff earnings by: (4) Staff_Effort x (3) team_rate_of_pay 
    Multiply the individual's effort by the team rate he worked at on the day.
    This one is ridiculously slow. In fact, it's useless.

```
CREATE View staff_earnings AS
SELECT 
    staff_effort.StaffDate
   ,staff_effort.StaffID
   ,sum(staff_effort.StaffEffort) AS StaffEffort 
   ,sum([StaffEffort]*[TeamRate]) AS StaffEarn
FROM staff_effort INNER JOIN team_rate_of_pay
ON (staff_effort.TeamID = team_rate_of_pay.TeamID) 
AND (staff_effort.StaffDate = team_rate_of_pay.Date)
Group By  
    staff_effort.StaffDate, 
    staff_effort.StaffID;
```

So you see what I mean.... I need various results and subsequent queries are dependent on those results.

What I tried to do is to write a view for each of the above steps and then just use the view in the next step and so on.  They work fine but view nr 3 runs slower than the rest, even though still acceptable.  View nr 5 is just ridiculously slow.

I actually have another view after nr.5 which brings hours worked into play as well but that just takes forever to produce a few rows.

I want a single line for each staff member, showing what he earned each day calculated as set out above, with his hours worked each day.

I also tried to reduce the number of views by using sub-queries instead but that took even longer.

A little guidance / direction will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

--EDIT--

Taking the query posted in the comments. Did some formatting, added aliases and a little cleanup it would look like this.

```
SELECT epd.CompanyID
    ,epd.DATE
    ,epd.TeamID
    ,epd.Earn
    ,tb.TeamBags
    ,epd.Earn / tb.TeamBags AS RateperBag
FROM teamEarnPerDay epd
INNER JOIN teamBags tb ON epd.DATE = tb.TeamDate
    AND epd.TeamID = tb.TeamID;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, your current query, and an appropriate database tag would make this question much more answerable.

Comment: I added a sql-server tag.   The separate queries are really simple and they basically do what I described above.  I am posting the first view that runs a little slower because it uses other views:    SELECT teamEarnPerDay.CompanyID, 
teamEarnPerDay.Date, 
teamEarnPerDay.TeamID, 
teamEarnPerDay.Earn, 
teamBags.TeamBags, 
[Earn]/[TeamBags] AS RateperBag
FROM teamEarnPerDay 
INNER JOIN teamBags 
ON (teamEarnPerDay.Date = teamBags.TeamDate) 
AND (teamEarnPerDay.TeamID = teamBags.TeamID);

Comment: The problem is that some views are slow?

Comment: Posting queries in the comments is not a good idea. It is part of your question. And the formatting in comments is horrific for code. But it sounds like you have embarked on using nested views. Seems logical but is one of the worst things you can do for performance. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: I posted my code and a little more info like the nr of records I am working with.  Any input will be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any indexes defined on your tables?

Comment: I don't believe this is your code -- you have a syntax error on the first view.  There is a comma before the first field.  `SELECT ,Units_Done.Date, `  and you have commas at the start AND end of ever line??!

Comment: I just changed the views, tables and field names to match the example I used and to make them shorter.  Other than that the code is identical. I also deleted extra fields that would just make the code longer but with no bearing on what is discussed.  Those commas were just left there by accident where an extra field was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually did 2 things:
1)  Managed to reduce the nr of nested views by using sub-queries.  This did not improve performance by much but it seems simpler with fewer views.

2)  The actual improvement was caused by using LEFT JOIN in stead of Inner Join.
The final view ran for 50 minutes with the Inner Join without producing a single row yet.
With LEFT JOIN, it produced all the results in 20 seconds!

Hope this helps someone.